# Link style on the main site

Tags: bug, design

Is [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1453/184706) still active?
According to that thread there are supposed to be fine dotted lines beneath links. I have no such lines. Sometimes I actually do miss the links in the color scheme.

**Links as they are supposed to be:**

[image: English link color]

**Links as they are (at least on my devices):**

[image]